# tikz in poster with form beamer

Tags: beamerposter

With the template http://www.latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster I want to make a diagram in introduction.

I used the package 'tikz-cd' so I add this package, but then I get a error because of `\begin{frame}[t] \end{frame}`.

For example, I want to draw a diagram

```
$\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.5em,column sep=0.5em, ]
 A  \arrow[dd, bend right=120, "b"] \arrow[rrr,"f"]\arrow[d, "q"] &&& C \arrow[d, "U(1)"] \\
 D \arrow[d, "" ]&&& E \\
F \arrow[rrr] &&&  G
\end{tikzcd}$
```

in the above template.
Then the error says

```
'Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options 
> l.352 \end{frame}
% End of the enclosing frame'
```

Then what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the option `fragile` to `\begin{frame}[...]` options, then you have only one error that you can fix deleting or moving to the next line the comment after `\end{frame} %...`.

Seems amazing but it works.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,fragile] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame
\begin{block}{Introduction}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.5em,column sep=0.5em,]
 A  \arrow[dd, bend right=120, "b"] \arrow[rrr,"f"]\arrow[d, "q"] &&& C \arrow[d, "U(1)"] \\
 D \arrow[d, "" ]&&& E \\
F \arrow[rrr] &&&  G
\end{tikzcd}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Here it is. Maybe too long but this is the code. You have to download the images from the link in the answer.

Comment: Please roll back my edit if you don't like it. The code as is now works, and is perhaps enough to demonstrate the validity of your answer.\